# How to set up all coefficients to be positive in Solving an integer equation using Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, integer, equation

Given a vector `A=[a_1, a_2, a_3,...,a_n]`, where a_i are integers, now
solving an equation
`∑a_i x_i=0` with x_i>=0, and x_i to be integers.

Using Mathematica, we can write some code like
`Solve[A . Table[x[i], {i, n}] =  0 && Table[x[i] > 0, {i, n}], Integers]`
But the conditions above `Table[x[i] > 0` is not rightly coded. It should be `x[1]>0 && x[2]>0 && x[3]>0 &&...x[n]>0`. Is there any easy way to write such code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reduce.html) not `Solve`, as `Reduce` can handle inequalities. As to turning `Table[x[i] > 0, {i, n}]` into `x[1] > 0 && ... && x[n] > 0` that's straightforward:

```
And @@ Table[x[i] > 0, {i, n}]
```

which uses the short form of [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) (`@@`) to turn

```
List[x[1] > 0, ..., x[n] > 0]
```

into

```
And[x[1] > 0, ..., x[n] > 0]
```

Or, more visually,

```
x[1] > 0 && ... && x[n] > 0
```